# Is there a way to make Tor network your full VPN?

Tags: vpn, tor

Is there a way to use Tor network as your VPN, proxy or something alike?

I have been gone to their website but I've seen just browser (Tor Browser), bridge, relay and exit.

Is there way to tell Linux? "Hey, connect to Tor network like browser, use that IP and send data through that hole."

Answer (score 3):

One of the easiest ways to do this, is through the use of visualization.
Where your Host machine runs the TOR client, and starts the virtual environment.

Details of this on the tor.stackexchange.com

Example post : 
[Running a virtual machine (VM) that can only connect through Tor](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/330/running-a-virtual-machine-vm-that-can-only-connect-through-tor)

This allows you to run apps and sessions inside your virtual environment just like you would on your regular host OS, while safe in the knowledge, "anything and everything in this environment is using the TOR network,"

Answer (score 2):

Speaking as someone who's set up such a system, my recommendation is that you simply use the [Tails](https://tails.boum.org/) distro, possibly in a virtualized environment.  It's much easier, and the Tails developers have already put in the effort of looking for ways that data can leak.

If you want to set things up yourself, study Tails and see how it handles things.  You'll basically need to go through each network-accessing application and configure it to use TOR, either directly or through SOCKS encapsulation.

Answer (score 1):

While not a complete solution, with the tour browser bundle running, on a Linux system, you can invoke command line utilities proceeded by the command "torsocks" to make the command argument go through the all ready running tor demon.

Be careful though. As other posters have said, a distro like Tails, or encapsulating everything in a VM forced to go through Tor may be a more complete solution.

It depends how paranoid you need to be for your individual use case.  But "torsocks" is a handy little utility for quick, one off command line usage.

Answer (score 1):

Yes although not ideal, you can use obfuscated bridges to hide the fact that you're using tor from your ISP, although there are more things you must do to prevent them from recognizing the traffic when they do deep packet inspection and you can use tor as system wide proxy with software such a proxychains, you can also manually configure services or application to route through tor by changing the proxy server settings to route through 127.0.0.1 and through port 9050. Its definitely doable but not ideal as your traffic leaving the exit node is unencrypted, use tor connect to your vpn that way not even your vpn (should it be compromised, or they lied about not logging IP's) can determine your location providing the best anonymity. Of course you can use virtualization as suggested in the answers before me as well.